# Coldfusion SOAP Exception Error Handling

Tags: exception, soap, coldfusion

How can I customize a SOAP error message in ColdFusion? Most languages like PHP, Java, .NET etc. have this capability. While I've seen this question asked on other sites, none of the threads contained an answer. If this isn't possible, I think Adobe should add a patch to support this feature.

Here is an example of the SOAP error in ColdFusion:

**SOAP Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**SOAP Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.Exception: Body not found.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:stackTrace xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">java.lang.Exception: Body not found.
                at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:121)
                ...</ns1:stackTrace>
            <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">Coldfusion Error</ns2:hostname>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In other languages you can customize the error message like so:

**SOAP Response:**

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>BODY_NOT_FOUND</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Body is missing in your request</faultstring>

      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I haven't found a way to achieve this in ColdFusion. We are planning to upgrade to ColdFusion 11. Does ColdFusion 11 (or below) have a way to do this?

Comment: I believe ColdFusion 9 introduced the [onCFCRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe821657cd7d6f83f6daaa733122cf6931bb-8000.html) method in Application.cfc that "_Intercepts any HTTP or AMF calls to an application based on CFC request._" Have you tried that to see if it is called before the standard error message is sent?

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know how the application is generating and receiving requests to begin with.  With ColdFusion, to create a request, you would start by creating the SOAP Packet you want to send:

```
<cfsavecontent variable = "variable name"> 
    <XML></XML>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Next, use CFHTTP to send your SOAP request out:

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html

When your response comes back and you have assigned it to a variable (set up in your CFHTTP request) you can use this response variable to determine how to parse the response.  So for example, you might use XMLParse or XMLSearch to find the elements and process them.

See:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category/xml-functions.html

Note that special configuration might be required if network protocols are to be observed - for instance, SSLv3/TLS.  Consult your network administrator to determine if any configuration of ColdFusion needs to be done to support network architecture.  Also validate that your endpoints can see each other through any firewalls.  For more connection information consult either the ColdFusion documentation or threads relevant to your situation such as:

[Does cfhttp for coldfusion 10 only supports up to TLS 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046087/does-cfhttp-for-coldfusion-10-only-supports-up-to-tls-1-0)