# Does cfhttp for coldfusion 10 only supports up to TLS 1.0?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Does cfhttp for coldfusion 10 only supports up to tls 1.0?

When I disable tls 1.0 in the web server only allowed 1.1 and higher it seems to break the scheduled tasks.

CF 10 with JRE 1.6

Comment: More information regarding SSL compatibility is available here: http://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2014/12/8/Preventing-SSLv3-Fallback-in-ColdFusion

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with the Java version you are using, not CF10.

TLS 1.1 is only supported in Java 1.8 on CF10 (Oddly 1.7 and above in CF11)

See this Adobe Blog as a starting guide to updating your Java.

http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/how-to-change-upgrade-jdk-version-of-coldfusion-server

> 1. **Using ColdFusion administrator console.**
>
>    - Download the latest minor version of the supported JDK or Server JRE.
>    - Install the JDK or Server JRE.
>    - Navigate to ColdFusion Administrator > Server Settings >
>        Java and JVM section.
>    - Browse the path to the JDK or Server JRE from
>        the “Java Virtual Machine Path” textbox which you intended to use with
>        ColdFusion.
>    - Click “Submit Changes”. Restart the ColdFusion Application
>        service.
> 2. **By changing the JDK or Server JRE path from the jvm.config file.**
>
>    - Download the latest minor version of the supported JDK or Server JRE.
>    - Install the JDK or Server JRE.
>    - Open jvm.config file located at
>        \cfusion\bin.
>    - Change the value of java.home to the
>        JDK or Server JRE path. [For example: C:\Program
>        Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre or C:/Program
>        Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre]
>    - Save the changes to the jvm.config file.
>    - Restart the ColdFusion Application service.

You will require Update 14 and above if you want to install Java 1.8 on CF10