# I m getting 'Stripe doesn't support HTTPS connections with TLS 1.0' error when calling stripe API

Tags: coldfusion, tls1.2, coldfusion-10

I am getting below error when accessing the stripe API using ColdFusion.

> Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does cfhttp for coldfusion 10 only supports up to TLS 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046087/does-cfhttp-for-coldfusion-10-only-supports-up-to-tls-1-0)

Answer (score 1):

This is related JRE issue in coldfusion. Most of the payment gateways doesn't support TLS 1.0. So, we need to update the Java JRE in our coldfusion server.

**How to fix:**

1. Upgrade to Java 8.
2. Login to ColdFusion Administrator > Java JVM
3. Change the path of the JVM to the new installed path (defaults to: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102 in windows. )
4. Restart ColdFusion Server - Service.
5. Re-Test.. it should work now..

Comment: If you have any other certs that you had to import in the previous Java keystore, I believe you'll have to reimport them after this update.